# Coin Change: number of solutions when order matters vs. when order doesn't matter

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I solved the coin change problem with dynamic programming with the following functions count_distinct and count_perm, which both give the number of solutions for the given amount of money (parameter x) and the coins in use (parameter c). The vector d is used for memoization: it records the number of solutions for each nonnegative amount of money, i.e. for the values {0,1,...,x}.

As an example, when the amount of money is 5 and the coins in use are {2, 3, 4}, count_distinct gives the result 1 (it considers the solutions {2, 3} and {3, 2} as equal), and count_perm gives the result 2 (it considers them as different solutions).

I don't understand the reason for why this happens. In the two functions, the loop variables are in opposite order, but I don't see why that should matter. Also, the indexation in count_distinct takes care that negative amounts of money aren't evaluated, and the corresponding check is done with the continue-statement in count_perm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

long count_distinct(int x, vector <long> c) {

    vector <long> d(x+1);
    d[0] = 1;
    int k = c.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = c[i]; j <= x; j++) {
            d[j] += d[j - c[i]];
        }
    }
    return d[x];   
}

long count_perm(int x, vector <long> c) {

    vector <long> d(x + 1);
    d[0] = 1;
    int k = c.size();

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (i - c[j] < 0) continue;
            d[i] += d[i - c[j]];
        }
    }
    return d[x];
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    vector <long> c;
    c.push_back(2);
    c.push_back(3);
    c.push_back(4);

    long distinct = count_distinct(x, c);
    long perms = count_perm(x, c);
    cout << distinct << endl;
    cout << perms << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just write down on a piece of paper all the variable names, as column headings.  Then go step by step through the routines and write down the values of each variable at each step.  You'll figure it out.

Comment: You should be analysing whether and how each function works, not (directly) try to tell the difference between the two. Have you tested the code on different / larger inputs to validate that it does actually work?

Comment: I have tested both of the functions with different inputs and they seem to give correct results. I'll go through them with pen and paper to see if I can figure it out.